# How can i get clear -export function names from built DLL? I always get originalname+gibberish

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

note: First of all i am using visual studio 2010.

Usually i need dll with some exported functions that i need to use from outside apps..

Normally this is how my dll header looks...

```
#define DLLAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLAPI BOOL WINAPI FUNCTION1(...);
DLLAPI BOOL WINAPI FUNCTION2(...);
```

I don't add any commands to the project or anything, all i do to export them is this in the headers + add DLLAPI to functions in the source file ofc.

Now when i need to get the function name from my outside app its making me problems because its always something like FUNCTION1xa1@assu79sax_ or something like that...

I saw a project which uses .DEF file and makes its headers like...

```
// INCLUDE FILE generated by "Pelles C for Windows, version 3.00".

#ifndef _HOOK_H
#define _HOOK_H

#ifdef _HOOK_
#define HOOKAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define HOOKAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif /* _HOOK_ */

#ifndef WINAPI
#define WINAPI  __stdcall
#endif

HOOKAPI int WINAPI SampleFunction(int, int);

#endif /* _HOOK_H */
```

and it's .def file looks like...

```
EXPORTS
    SetValuesCBT
    SetValuesKey
    SetValuesMouse
    MouseProc
    KeyProc
    CBTProc

SECTIONS
    .shared READ WRITE SHARED
```

This results in very clear function names exported aka just as they are called(as proven by dumpbin.exe) btw if matters, it also has .pjj file with following content...

```
# 
# PROJECT FILE generated by "Pelles C for Windows, version 5.00".
# WARNING! DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
# 

POC_PROJECT_VERSION = 5.00.1#
POC_PROJECT_TYPE = 1#
POC_PROJECT_ARGUMENTS = #
CC = pocc.exe#
AS = #
RC = porc.exe#
LINK = polink.exe#
SIGN = posign.exe#
CCFLAGS = -Tx86-coff -Ot -W1 -Ze -Gz#
ASFLAGS = -c -nologo -coff -W1 -Cu#
RCFLAGS = -r#
LINKFLAGS = -machine:ix86 -subsystem:windows kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib comctl32.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib delayimp.lib -dll#
WizCreator = Pelle Orinius#
SIGNFLAGS = -location:CU -store:MY -timeurl:http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll -errkill#
INCLUDE = $(PellesCDir)\Include\Win;$(PellesCDir)\Include#
LIB = $(PellesCDir)\Lib\Win;$(PellesCDir)\Lib#

.SILENT:

# 
# Build hook.dll.
# 
hook.dll: \
    output\DLL.obj \
    EXPORTS.DEF
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) -out:"$@" $**

# 
# Build DLL.obj.
# 
output\DLL.obj: \
    DLL.C
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) "$!" -Fo"$@"

.EXCLUDEDFILES:
```

I don't know how should i emulate this in my VS 2010 project so when i build my dll function names are simple and precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the DEF file as you've shown above with just your two functions and go into the link options and specify to use this def file.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34c30xs1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> The /DEF option passes a
>   module-definition file (.def) to the
>   linker. Only one .def file can be
>   specified to LINK. For details about
>   .def files, see Module-Definition
>   Files. To set this linker option in
>   the Visual Studio development
>   environment
>
> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see
>      Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.
> 2. Click the Linker folder.
> 3. Click the Input property page.
> 4. Modify the Module Definition File property.
>
> To specify a .def file from within the
>   development environment, you should
>   add it to the project along with other
>   files and then specify the file to the
>   /DEF option.